# Scipy: Brute (grid-search) with multi threading?

Tags: python, multithreading, scipy

I'm using [`scipy.optimize.brute()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brute.html), but I noticed that it's only using one of my cores. One big advantage of a grid-search is to have all iterations of the solutions algorithm independent of each other.

Given that that's the case - why is `brute()` not implemented to run on multiple cores? If there is no good reason - is there a quick way to extend it / make it work, or does it make more sense to write the whole routine from scratch?

Answer (score 3):

`scipy.optimize.brute` takes an arbitrary Python function. There is no guarantee this function is threadsafe. Even if it is, Python's global interpreter lock means that unless the function bypasses the GIL in C, it can't be run on more than one core anyway.

If you want to parallelize your brute-force search, you should write it yourself. You may have to write some Cython or C to get around the GIL.

Comment: *"unless the function bypasses the GIL in C, it can't be run on more than one core anyway"* - that's not strictly true. The GIL means that the CPython interpreter can only execute one native thread at a time, but you *can* spawn multiple instances of the interpreter in separate processes and then use these to execute jobs concurrently on multiple cores. That's how the `multiprocessing` module works.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have scikit-learn installed? With a bit of refactoring you could use [`sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV), which supports multiprocessing via `joblib`.

You would need to wrap your local optimization function as an object that exposes [the generic scikit-learn estimator interface](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html#rolling-your-own-estimator), including a `.score(...)` method (or you could pass in a separate scoring function to the `GridSearchCV` constructor via the `scoring=` kwarg).